# R Looping through multiple similar dataframes and remove partial strings from columns of each DF

Tags: r

I have multiple csv files namely test9 to test15.
All the file has the similar structure below

[image]

**data**

```
structure(list(x = structure(c(7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("CASE TEST 9 1A", "CASE TEST 9 2A", 
"CASE TEST 9 3A", "CASE TEST 9 4A", "CASE TEST 9 BOX ", "CASE TEST 9 Delta", 
"CASE TEST 9 Inlet ", "CASE TEST 9 Outlet ", "CASE TEST 9 Total "
), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(9L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 7L), .Label = c("CASE TEST 9 1A", "CASE TEST 9 4A", 
"CASE TEST 9 BOX ", "CASE TEST 9 BOX Flow", "CASE TEST 9 BOX Total ", 
"CASE TEST 9 Gett", "CASE TEST 9 Inlet", "CASE TEST 9 Outlet", 
"CASE TEST 9 Outlet ", "CASE TEST 9 Total "), class = "factor"), 
    cdf = c(0.944604888, 0.874809846, 0.691878303, 0.524043157, 
    0.943973621, 0.687799043, 0.5105407, 0.989077927, -0.58787388, 
    0.036798229, 0.780733881, 0.116990659, 0.770803109), abscorr = c(0.944604888, 
    0.874809846, 0.691878303, 0.524043157, 0.943973621, 0.687799043, 
    0.5105407, 0.989077927, 0.58787388, 0.036798229, 0.780733881, 
    0.116990659, 0.770803109)), .Names = c("x", "y", "cdf", "abscorr"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

I like to loop through each files and remove the text "CASE TEST 'z'" in column x and y.
I understand I can use gsub to remove them for each dataframe, but if I were to use a loop, how I can make sure that the string to remove will change accordingly to the file name.

- test9: remove "CASE TEST 9"
- test10: remove "CASE TEST 10"
- etc etc.

Output should look something like this for each dataframes:
[image]

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: in your case, you have factor columns in x and y. Is this by design or by accident?

Comment: @mnist I added a picture for the desired output. yes it was accidental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would my workflow on this look like?

1. Create a list of `.csv` files to be read in. If there are multiple files I prefer storing them in a list instead of multiple, single data.frames. A list is easier to handle and we can avoid `get`-`assign`-structures in an automated/loop workflow.

```r
# set work directory if necessary
# setwd("C:/testfiles")

files <- list.files(pattern = "csv$")
```

2. Read in those `.csv` files. I prefer using `readr` but base Rs `read.csv` is okay.

```r
# readr version
# test_files <- lapply(files, function(x) readr::read_csv2(x))
test_files <- lapply(files, function(x) read.csv2(x))
```

3. Name the list.

```r
names(test_files) <- gsub("\\.csv", "", files)
```

4. Clean up the data.frames.

```r
# base R version
result <- Map(
  function(file) {
    transform(file, 
              x = gsub("(^\\s*|CASE TEST \\d+\\s*|\\s*$)", "", x),
              y = gsub("(^\\s*|CASE TEST \\d+\\s*|\\s*$)", "", y)
              )
    },
  test_files
  )

# tidyverse version
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

result <- test_files %>%
  map(
    ~.x %>%
      mutate(
        across(c(x, y), ~str_trim(str_remove(.x, "CASE TEST \\d+\\s*")))
      )
  )
```

5. Access each data.frame in the list.

```
# test9
result[["test9"]]
# or
result$test9


# test10
result[["test10"]]
# or
result$test10
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this could also work fine for your purpose. I noticed there are some trailing white spaces in your values in variable `x` and `y` so the last line of code just makes sure they are removed.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x, y), ~ 
    gsub("CASE\\sTEST\\s\\d+\\s(.*)", "\\1", .x, perl = TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(across(c(x, y), ~ gsub("(.*)\\s$?", "\\1", .x)))

        x         y         cdf    abscorr
1   Inlet    Outlet  0.94460489 0.94460489
2   Inlet     Total  0.87480985 0.87480985
3  Outlet     Total  0.69187830 0.69187830
4  Outlet       BOX  0.52404316 0.52404316
5   Total       BOX  0.94397362 0.94397362
6   Total BOX Total  0.68779904 0.68779904
7     BOX  BOX Flow  0.51054070 0.51054070
8     BOX        1A  0.98907793 0.98907793
9      1A      Gett -0.58787388 0.58787388
10     2A    Outlet  0.03679823 0.03679823
11     3A        4A  0.78073388 0.78073388
12     4A    Outlet  0.11699066 0.11699066
13  Delta     Inlet  0.77080311 0.77080311
```

Comment: You can also load the stringr library and just use the function str_squish() and put the first gsub in it, i like your answer using the dplyr library

Comment: Yes it would be easier that way for sure. But I decided to take a break from `tidyverse` as much as I could so that I can practice base R a little bit. I think base R has so much for me to explore :)

Comment: There are ways to completely avoid `tidyverse`. :-)

Comment: I don't know where this tendency to use base R came from. I remember the first time I got to know `tidyverse` I was so thrilled that I totally abandoned base R but after a while I kinda sensed that there is an aura of authenticity with it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for :

```
my_test9 <- data.frame("x" = c("CASE TEST 9 a", "CASE TEST 9 b"),
                   "y" = c("CASE TEST 9 c", "CASE TEST 9 d"),
                   "cdf" = c(0.9, 0.1),
                   "abscorr" = c(0.9, 0.1),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_test10 <- data.frame("x" = c("CASE TEST 10 a", "CASE TEST 10 b"),
                    "y" = c("CASE TEST 10 c", "CASE TEST 10 d"),
                    "cdf" = c(0.9, 0.1),
                    "abscorr" = c(0.9, 0.1),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_test9$Number <- 9
my_test10$Number <- 10

my_list <- list(my_test9, my_test10)

my_function <- function(x) {
  my_pattern <- paste("CASE TEST ", unique(my_list[[x]]$Number), sep = "")
  my_list[[x]]$x <<- gsub(pattern = my_pattern, replacement = "", x = my_list[[x]]$x)
  my_list[[x]]$y <<- gsub(pattern = my_pattern, replacement = "", x = my_list[[x]]$y)
}
my_var <- lapply(1:length(my_list), my_function)

my_test9 <- my_list[[1]]
my_test10 <- my_list[[2]]
```

Comment: it's bad habit to use the super assignment operator (`<<-`). Neither is it unavoidable here